# How to recursively inherit a template class from itself? (not CRTP!)

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am going to try an interesting trick!
I want to recursively build an inheritance of template classes.

I am expecting to see this:

```
T<int, int, int> inherits T<int,int> inherits T<int> inherits T<void>
```

```
/*Here should be specializations with void...*/

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class ToPack : ToPack<Ts...>
{
public:
    ToPack(T t, Ts... ts) : ToPack(ts...) {}
};

template<typename T>
class ToPack<T, void> {};

 int main(void)
{
     ToPack<int, int, int> t(1, 2, 3);
}
```

But the problem is that when the compiler tries to instantiate `T<int>` it tries to unpack variadic template parameters for "parent" class and it fails, i.e.

```
ToPack<int> -> actually ToPack<int, void> that tries to unpack ToPack<void...>
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: `s/T<void>/T<>`? - `void` is actually a type, not a placeholder for no type. It's not in the pack, so the expansion isn't going to end in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `void` is itself a type, not a placeholder for empty. What you really have is `ToPack<int, int, int>` -> `ToPack<int, int>` -> `ToPack<int>` -> `ToPack<>`. `ToPack<>` isn't valid since it requires at least one template parameter, so this fails to compile.

You need to change your base case by specializing on one template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class ToPack : ToPack<Ts...> {
public:
    ToPack(T t, Ts... ts) : ToPack<Ts...>(ts...) {}
};

template <typename T>
class ToPack<T> {
public:
    ToPack(T t) {}
};
```